# Setting up connection signalr angular 6

Tags: angular, signalr

I am migrating from AngularJs to Angular6 and want to use `@aspnet/signalr npm package`.

I am trying to set up the SignalR connection and having issues. My old connection using jQuery SignalR was the below.

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'https://test.localhost.com/api/signalr';
$.connection.hub.qs = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*";
var hub = $.connection.servicelog;
hub.client.newInformation = function (data) {
        //do something
    };
hub.client.newInformation2 = function (data) {
        //Do something else
    };

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   $log.debug('connection started to signalrHub app info');
});
```

As you can see the Signalr is on another domain and hence adding the header.

My hub name is called 'servicelog'

I cannot figure out how to set this up using `HubConnection` or `HubConnectionBuilder` in my new Angular 6 project.

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('https://test.localhost.com/api/signalr' + '/servicelog')
  .build();
connection.start().then(()=>{
  console.log('Hub connection started');
}).catch((err)=>{
  console.log('Error establishing connection - ' + err);
});
```

I cannot find where to set the Access control header as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';
class yourcomponentclass
{
      private _hubConnection: HubConnection;
      ngOnInit(): void {
    this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('url placed here').build();
    this._hubConnection
      .start()

      .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :()'));
    this._hubConnection.on('BroadcastMessage', (type: string, rating: number[]) => {

        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add an explenation how this code works and how it solves the question